# How do I get a grid to match up between front and back of the same page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, alignment, double-sided, printing, grids

I've got this grid that I create using tikz (the actual code does more stuff, this is just an MWE). I'd like to print it two-sided such that, if you look at the sheet with a backlight, the lines would align. In other words, corners of the grid on front and back would be right on top one another. Is this possible?

Edit: I'm using XeLateX for this, if that is important

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,
left=.5cm,
right=.5cm,
top=.5cm,
bottom=.5cm,
footskip=0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=gray, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, dashed},
    %default radius will be 1pt. 
    cross/.default={1pt}}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newcounter{col}
\newcounter{row}

\newcommand\grid[4]{%
    \def\colnames{#1}%
    \def\size{#2}%
    \def\sep{#3}%
    \def\empties{#4}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\inc}{\size+\sep}
    \setcounter{col}{0}
    \setcounter{row}{0}
    \foreach \colname in \colnames{
        \addtocounter{col}{1}
        \setcounter{row}{0}
        \foreach \empt in \empties{
            \addtocounter{row}{1}
            \draw ({(\thecol-1)*\inc+\size*0.5 pt},{\therow*\size+\size*0.5})
            node[cross=\size*0.35,rotate=45,darkgray]{};
            \draw[black] ({(\thecol-1)*\inc pt},{\therow*\size})
            rectangle ++ (\size,\size);
        }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
    
\centering

\grid{o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o}{10mm}{0mm}{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
\newpage
\grid{o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o}{10mm}{0mm}{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the center of the page as `(0,0)`, then it is just a matter of investing in a printer that can make alignment of significantly less than a line width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift=(current page.center)]
\draw (-10,-13) grid (10,13);
\draw[dashed, dash pattern=on 1mm off 1mm on 1mm off 1mm on 1mm off 0mm, shift={(0.5,0.5)}] (-10.5,-13.5) grid (9.5,12.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, shift=(current page.center)]
\draw (-10,-13) grid (10,13);
\draw[dashed, dash pattern=on 1mm off 1mm on 1mm off 1mm on 1mm off 0mm, shift={(0.5,0.5)}] (-10.5,-13.5) grid (9.5,12.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two pages with grid]

Comment: Thanks, that's easier than mine... so I guess `[remember picture, overlay, shift=(current page.center)]` is the only setting that is necessary for the alignment. Can I use that with any `tikzpicture` to align front and back, then?

Comment: @Zubo: You can use that to make the coordinate `(0,0)` to be at the center of the page. (needs two compilations). This will automatically align pages with symmetrical contend.